# Session Cookies and Android

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with my android program and session cookies.

The Session is just not being held between calls, even thought i am using cookieStore.
The Webserver code is written in DJango, but the session is preserved when i use a C program with libcurl.

```
public class JSON {
...
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
    CookieStore cookieStore;
    HttpContext httpContext;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    HttpGet httpGet = null;
public JSON(Context context) {
    f_context = context;
    updateSettings();
    HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
    cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
}
...
public String JSONSendCmd(String methodName) {
    String getUrl = URL + "json/" + methodName+'/';
    httpGet = new HttpGet(getUrl);
    try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,httpContext);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Probably because of initiating/using DefaultHttpClient multiple times across multiple activities, where and how do you involve new JSON(); and xxx.JSONSendCmd();?

Comment: Actually, in each activity when i enter, i authenticate, and when i leave, i deauthenticate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

if (!cookies.isEmpty())
{

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(ClientContext.getInstance());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    // sync all the cookies in the httpclient with the webview
    // by generating cookie string
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies)
    {
        Cookie sessionInfo = cookie;

        String cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue() + ";    domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
                            cookieManager.setCookie(ClientContext.getResources().getString(R.string.domain), cookieString);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }
}
```